# click a link in 1 frame and open site in 2nd frame

Tags: php, html

I  have 2 frames and in 1st frame there is a link i want that when i click on link a website should be opened i 2nd frame .

```
<html>


<html>
<frameset cols="25%,75%,">
<frame src="left.html" name="terminator">
<FRAME    name="terminator2"  >


</frameset>
</html>
```

And in left.html

```html
<html>
<body>


<a href="https://www.google.com.pk/?gws_rd=ssl" target="terminator2">Link</a>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: html5 is not the correct tag for this question as <frame> is not supported in the html5 spec. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp

Comment: @FunkDoc then how can i do something like this ?

Comment: `name` and `target` would be the correct way of doing it.. Perhaps you should try specifying an xhtml or html4 doctype.